# Can not find <eosiolib/eosio.hpp> when compiling with eosiocpp

Tags: smart-contract

I am trying to compile the [Hello World Tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/hello-world), using the following command:

```
eosiocpp -o hello.wast hello.cpp
```

However, this does not work, giving the error:

```
hello.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'eosiolib/eosio.hpp' file not found
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
```

There were suggestions in the Git Issue Tracker that this could be fixed by running:

```
sudo make install
```

in the eos/build directory, but I tried this and it didn't work for me.

Does anyone know what is wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: I found a temporary solution that pushes the problem along to a different point. If you make a symbolic link to the eos/contracts/eoslib directory in the folder where you are trying to use eosiocpp, then you can get further with the compilation. Leading to the new problem of the stdint.h header not being found. Will post more updates as I make further progress.

Comment: my suggestion would be to erase the `eos/build`, run `eosio_build.sh` again, go into the new `eos/build` folder and run `sudo make install`

Comment: I have this same issue but on OSX with CDT v1.6.1 with the Brew install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own problem.

This seems to be a bug in the build script for EOS (see [Github Issue 4690](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4690)) that isn't fixed for all platforms.

I was running EOS on Ubuntu 18.04. Have now switched down to 16.04 and everything works fine.

Comment: But I have ubuntu 16.04 yet I face the same problem , I also tried `sudo make install`

Comment: I have seen this bug appear many times for many different reasons. It could be one of the other ones. Check the following: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/can-not-find-eosiolib-eosio-hpp-when-compiling-with-eosiocpp-2 and https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/what-is-needed-to-get-the-eos-1-1-4-tutorials-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-having-c

Answer (score 1):

0
down vote

As a workaround, revert locally the commit which introduced a regression, then build and install again:

```
cd $HOME/eos
git revert -n 67393d7
./eosio_build.sh
cd build
sudo make install
```

eosiocpp should work now fine.

Full details within:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5133

Comment: I do the same for unbuntu 16.04 when i compile my file i got the error `/usr/local/eosio/include/eosiolib/symbol.hpp:2:10: fatal error: 'eosiolib/core_symbol.hpp' file not found
#include <eosiolib/core_symbol.hpp>` it seems this time this found asset.hpp but not able to find  `core_symbol.hpp` can  you please  suggest me what am i doing wrong here

Comment: fetch the latest code, then

    ./eosio_build.sh
    sudo ./eosio_install.sh

Comment: see https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5419#issuecomment-416004089