# Can not find <eosiolib/eosio.hpp> when compiling with eosiocpp #2

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, compilation

I'm trying to compile any smart contract. Let's say the skeleton one. When running eosiocpp -o it can't find the header file for eosio.
Not a duplicate of [Can not find <eosiolib/eosio.hpp> when compiling with eosiocpp](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/can-not-find-eosiolib-eosio-hpp-when-compiling-with-eosiocpp) because changing to 16.04 didn't work for me. Experienced this issue on both 18.04 and 16.04.

Also as you can see the programs haven't installed properly so I have to run the executables from where they were built.

`cd $EOS_ROOT/build; 
sudo make install; 
cd contracts; 
sudo ./../tools/eosiocpp -n hello2;
sudo ./../tools/eosiocpp -o hello2/hello2.wast hello2/hello2.cpp`

yields

```
hello2/hello2.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'eosiolib/eosio.hpp' file not found
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same here with MAC OS 10.12.6 and EOS version 1.1.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used `sudo make install`, then you should use the `eosiocpp` binaries generated for you. In the latest version, I believe they shoud be in `/usr/local/eosio/bin/` (it should print this info when `sudo make install` is finished if it's a different path) so add that to your `$PATH`:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/eosio/bin/:$PATH
$ which eosiocpp
/usr/bin/eosio/bin/eosiocpp
$ eosiocpp -n hello
$ eosiocpp -o hello/hello.wasm hello/hello.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue for eosiocpp in version 1.1.2/1.1.3 of the eosio/eos Github repo. **Switching to version 1.1.0 solved the problem for me** and a colleague.

Here's a host of issues relating to the problem:

- [Github 5015](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5015)
- [Github 5039](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5039)
- [Github 5040](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5040)
- [Github 4974](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4974)

Comment: Can you link us to the Github issue number?

Comment: Switching to 1.1.0 solved issue for me. Hope this issue will be fixed in a new patch.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, revert locally the commit which introduced a regression, then build and install again:

```
cd $HOME/eos
git revert -n 67393d7
./eosio_build.sh
cd build
sudo make install
```

eosiocpp should work now fine.

Full details within:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5133