# Issue while compiling contract using eosiocpp

Tags: cleos, eosio-code, eosio.token

I am facing an issue while compiling the token contract.

```
    cd eos/contract/eosio.token

    eosiocpp -o eosio.token.wast eosio.token.cpp
```

But it shows the following response,

```
    eosiocpp: command not found
```

Shall I need to install the compiler for doing the operation.
I have installed the EOSIO using the Source.

Comment: `cd` to build directory, `sudo make install`, check the output at the end to see where the binaries were installed, add that to your `$PATH`. maybe [this answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1721/961) helps too

Comment: @confused00 Issue fixed...Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not find <eosiolib/eosio.hpp> when compiling with eosiocpp #2](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/can-not-find-eosiolib-eosio-hpp-when-compiling-with-eosiocpp-2)

Comment: added an answer so people who come here don't have to search through comments and so the question doesn't show up as having no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building, if you want your binaries installed system-wide, you need to run in the build folder

```
$ sudo make install
```

Afterwards, the script should output where the binaries have been copied, and, if it's not already in the `$PATH`, you can extend your `$PATH` to look for them there. Example:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/eosio/bin/:$PATH
$ which eosiocpp
/usr/bin/eosio/bin/eosiocpp
$ eosiocpp -n hello
$ eosiocpp -o hello/hello.wasm hello/hello.cpp
```